# Writing data from my app to csv & upload it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file-upload, csv

I wondered if it's possible to write some data to CSV file in the documents path, or other convenient readable file.

For example - I have a few text fields that I want the user to fill & then I want him to click "send" & after that the information will be written to a file that I could easily read and upload to my server.

In my case I have an app that I want people to register for my members club, with first name, last name & phone number and I want to take this information and read it easily after its uploaded to my server.

For testing I'm using my dropbox account as a server.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just put all that data into NSDictionary, serialize it into JSON and send immediately via POST request without storing into file? Alternatively, you could store those NSDictionaries in NSUserDefaults for later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a few questions in one, but for the CSV part, you should have a look at Dave DeLong's [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser).

Comment: Thanks guys but i'm new in developing so i don't know yet how to use JSON & all the servers stuff :/... hope to find something usefull.

Comment: @MaorZohar Maybe it's easier for you to send that file as attachment via mail?

Comment: ott, when i think about it - yes it's an option.. i'll try to work it out. thanks...